# (Python 3.2) File Processing on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. Here are the text lines in a TXT file, the homework asks me to print them on a graphic window

```
student1 lastname 55
student4 lastname 55
student9 lastname 55
student10 lastname 55
student12 lastname 55
student15 lastname 55
```

So at first I opened the file, entered this loop and printed them on the python shell.

```
file = open("input.txt","r")
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Code for my graphic window

```
from graphics import *   
win = GraphWin('', 600,500)
```

Now how do I print those text lines on the Graphic window I just created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing good, but you should [read the docs](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html) for better understanding.

A better way to do what you want to do, would be

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin('', 600,500)
text_x, text_y = 200, 50
with open("input.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        label = Text(Point(text_x, text_y), line)
        label.draw(win)
        text_y += 50 # distance between 2 lines
```

Comment: I think you want `test_y` to be incremented, since it's lines

Comment: Oops. But apart from that, is the code correct? I am not much familiar with `grapics`.

Comment: I think yap, it's fine now.

Comment: i tried u method, but it only printed the last line of file on the window.

Comment: I tried this & it worked just fine as expected (atleast to print the lines). Please check your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the lines into a list using a basic list operation like

`line = [line.strip() for line in open("file.txt")]`

Once you get that the list and access each element in a `for` loop inside the window

I would recommend you to read through this  [pythongraphics doc](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html)

Comment: His method of doing it is actually better. The better pythonic way of doing it would be by using `with` statement. Also, you don't answer the actual question.